# Spark Standalone - Tmp Folder

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm working with Jupyter Notebook with Pyspark kernel on a node of a cluster, the problem is that my `/tmp` folder is always full. I already updated the parameters:

```
SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=172800"
```

The problem is that the folder has just 200GB, is there a way to say to spark clean when I shutdown the kernel in Jupyter? Or should I just set `Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl` to 30 min, so that every 30 min all the temp files/logs are deleted?

Comment: Can you try with spark.cleaner.ttl property? I am not sure though how it works. Just found one reference that it clears intermediate data.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll try that :). From the documentation it seems it works for data in memory not written on disk. I don't think is the right way but I'll try to read more about it.

Answer (score 1):

You might try changing the
spark.local.dir
parameter to a different location having more space.

See: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I really don't want to do that, I need all the space I can have, there should be a way to delete all the useless logs and files (not manually as I'm doing right now), or not generate them at all if not needed (I'm just prototyping in Jupyter, then I will go in cluster mode for production).